# Force a route to exit a subdomain in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm struggling with exiting out of a subdomain back up to the root domain in Rails 3.2.

Say I have a blog with a dashboard. Each user has a subdomain at `username.blog.com`. Each user also has a dashboard at `blog.com/dashboard`.

If a user manually types in `username.blog.com/dashboard`, I want them to be redirected to `blog.com/dashboard`.

I've tried using `subdomain => false` in my routes, but it seems to be of no use. I also tried a matcher underneath the domain scope, but that also didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Relevant routes.rb follows.

```
resource :dashboard, :controller => 'dashboard', :subdomain => false
scope '/', constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' } do
    get '/' => 'feed#show'
  end

root :to => 'dashboard#show', :subdomain => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep that logic outside the routing.
I would use dashboard_url instead of dashboard_path in my views / controllers.
I would put something like this in my ApplicationController

```
def dashboard_url(options={})
  options[:subdomain] = false
  super(options)
end
```

Comment: Sorry I left out the crucial part of my question. The issue isn't urls generated with helpers, but if the user manually types `/dashboard` to the end of a subdomain-url.

Comment: Then you should check for the subdomain in the controller. The controller shouldn't handle redirects. Or you can keep that logic outside the rails app and do the redirect in the webserver (nginx, apache, etc)

Comment: So then I could do a subdomain check in the controller and then do something with `:subdomain => false`?

Comment: yup. check for subdomain and redirect_to dashboard_url(subdomain: false)